# Is it possible to parameterize Logstash input sections?

Tags: configuration, logstash

We have configured Logstash file input using several very similar sections (see below). As you can see, sections are almost identical: they differ in "_application" and "_appPath" variables, the rest is the same. So I wonder if there is a way to parameterize Logstash input sections, so we could describe just one "file" parameter group but it will result in several "file" section instances, as shown below.

```
input {
  file {
    add_field => { "_environment" => "#{Octopus.Environment.Name}" }
    add_field => { "_application" => "potion" }
    add_field => { "_appPath" => "#{Octopus.Tentacle.Agent.ApplicationDirectoryPath}/%{[_environment]}/Potion" }
    path => "%{[_appPath]}/logs/log.*.txt"
    sincedb_path => "%{[_appPath]}/logs/sincedb"
    codec => "json"
    tags => [potion, local]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
  file {
    add_field => { "_environment" => "#{Octopus.Environment.Name}" }
    add_field => { "_application" => "bridge_soap" }
    add_field => { "_appPath" => "#{Octopus.Tentacle.Agent.ApplicationDirectoryPath}/%{[_environment]}/Bridge.Web" }
    path => "%{[_appPath]}/logs/log.*.txt"
    sincedb_path => "%{[_appPath]}/logs/sincedb"
    codec => json
    tags => [bridge_soap, local]
    start_position => "beginning"
   }
  file {
    add_field => { "_environment" => "#{Octopus.Environment.Name}" }
    add_field => { "_application" => "bridge_rest" }
    add_field => { "_appPath" => "#{Octopus.Tentacle.Agent.ApplicationDirectoryPath}/%{[_environment]}/Bridge.Rest.Host" }
    path => "%{[_appPath]}/logs/log.*.txt"
    sincedb_path => "%{[_appPath]}/logs/sincedb"
    codec => json
    tags => [bridge_rest, local]
    start_position => "beginning"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in logstash natively, but you could do something like it in your configuration management system (ansible, etc).